# Index-Id always has the same value for every input

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have dynamically created form that I would like to get index-id of certain inputs with names like championSpell[] I need to know which one is which so i thought of using index-id but it changes every inputs index to the same value when pressing add spell button. You can test the problem here http://89.69.172.125/test.php

```
$(function() {

             $('body').on('click', '#addSpell',function() { 

                  $(
                   '<p><select name="change[]" id="change[]" onchange="val(this)"><option value="Passive">Passive</option><option value="Q" selected>Q</option><option value="W">W</option><option value="E">E</option><option value="R">R</option></select><label for="var"><input type="text" id="championSpell[]" name="championSpell[]" data-id="" readOnly="true"><br><textarea type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Enter Description" /><select><option value="buff">Buff</option><option value="nerf">Nerf</option><option value="new">New</option><option value="change">Change</option><option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option></select></label> <a href="#" id="addGeneral">Add Change</a> <a href="#" id="remVar">Remove Spell</a></p>').appendTo($(this).next());
                     $('input[name="championSpell[]"]').attr('data-id', y);
                    y++;
                    return false;
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In you code **$('input[name="championSpell[]"]').attr('data-id', y);** this will change all inputs `data-id`. So instead of that directly add its data-id.
Like **data-id="'+y+'"**

I HAVE UPDATE YOUR CODE.

PLEASE TRY THIS CODE

```
$(function() {

             $('body').on('click', '#addSpell',function() { 
                  var championdataid = $('input[id="champion[]"]').attr('data-id');
                  $(
                   '<p><select name="change[]" id="change[]" onchange="val(this)"><option value="Passive">Passive</option><option value="Q" selected>Q</option><option value="W">W</option><option value="E">E</option><option value="R">R</option></select><label for="var"><input type="text" id="championSpell[]" name="championSpell[]" data-id="'+y+championdataid +'" readOnly="true"><br><textarea type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Enter Description" /><select><option value="buff">Buff</option><option value="nerf">Nerf</option><option value="new">New</option><option value="change">Change</option><option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option></select></label> <a href="#" id="addGeneral">Add Change</a> <a href="#" id="remVar">Remove Spell</a></p>').appendTo($(this).next());
                     //$('input[name="championSpell[]"]').attr('data-id', y);
                    y++;
                    return false;
            });
});
```

Comment: that helps but I have one more favor. One the website you can see that first you choose champion and then can add spells to it so i would like data-id be like x+y x - number of champion and y number of spell

Comment: i have update code: update for champion[]'s data-id+Y Please check code is this what you want?

Comment: Well I need an easy way to access them somehow after submitting the form so y has to reset somehow you have champion1 and you add e.g. 3 spells those spells will have id of 1 2 3 you will add 3 more spells to champion2 his ids wil be 4 5 6 and if you go back and add some more to champion1 it will be 7 8 9 and I need it to be like champion1 spells data id 1 2 3 4 5 6 champion2 1 2 3 4 and so on to later on access it easily

Comment: This is not what you ask in your post.... please ask same question as per your requirement...

Comment: yes, ask new question so it would be great. if you would want to up vote ans, you can

Answer (score 0):

Bad practice aside

(as in, using label as a block element)

(using jquery to create such a template file)

(etc)

(etc)

The problem resides with the variable `y` not being initialized, and changing all data-id values in the end. Try this updated (and a bit more readable) bit

```
$(function () {
    var y = 0;
    $('#addSpell').on('click', function(){
        $(['<p>',
                '<select name="change[]" id="change[]" onchange="val(this)">',
                    '<option value="Passive">Passive</option>',
                    '<option value="Q" selected>Q</option>',
                    '<option value="W">W</option>',
                    '<option value="E">E</option>',
                    '<option value="R">R</option>', 
                '</select>',
                '<label for="var">',
                    '<input type="text" id="championSpell[]" name="championSpell[]" data-id="' + y +'" readOnly="true">',
                    '<br>',
                    '<textarea type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + y + '" value="" placeholder="Enter Description">',
                    '<select>','' +
                        '<option value="buff">Buff</option>',
                        '<option value="nerf">Nerf</option>',
                        '<option value="new">New</option>',
                        '<option value="change">Change</option>',
                        '<option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option>',
                    '</select>',
                    '</label>',
                '<a href="#" id="addGeneral">Add Change</a>',
                '<a href="#" id="remVar">Remove Spell</a>',
        '</p>'].join('')).appendTo($(this).next());
        y++;
        return false;
    });
});
```